# Show user location on swift

Tags: swift, mapkit, core-location

I'm writing code that shows my location on a map.

I know that location can't work on a simulator really, but it can show a fake location with a blue circle.

In my map, it only shows a big map with no blue circle.
Why am I getting this error?

> (Could not retrieve region info)

It builds, but I get an error on output and it says:

> "2019-12-11 22:07:53.809967+0100 Ecologia[8465:265293] Metal API Validation Enabled
>   2019-12-11 22:07:54.001955+0100 Ecologia[8465:265293] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:1647: Could not retrieve region info"

This is my code:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Ecologia
//
//  Created by Antonio Trotta on 11/12/2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 Antonio Trotta. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Map: MKMapView!
    let locationManager:CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        Map.showsUserLocation = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you taking care of your `info.plist` before requesting the user's location?

Answer (score 0):

Check Simulator Menu: Debug > Location >

[image]